# Programmatic Testing With AAD User Accounts In Groups Synchronised Back to On-Premises AD

Tags: azure-active-directory

I want to do some automated tests of a web app (web api) in Azure that is secured with AAD. The customer is using on-premises AD to synch users and groups to AAD and is using ADFS to authenticate the users. This is enough, I believe, to stop me from using UserPasswordCredential to programmatically sign in a test user. So I have asked the customer to create me some cloud-only users that will be used in the automated tests. But we can’t add these users to the AAD groups, presumably because they are synched back to on-premises AD.

The web app is designed to check if its users are in a particular AAD group, but my test users can’t be in that group, so we may have to modify the app to check for multiple groups instead, and put the cloud-only tests users into a cloud-only group, so that we can add the cloud-only group to the list of groups allowed to call the web app.

Is this the best approach, or am I missing a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

UsernamePasswordCredential is meant to work with ADFS via federated tenant, as long as the proper endpoint is enabled in ADFS.